# ggplot a vector in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can simply plot a vector in R language using `plot`, like this:

```
vec <- sqrt(1:100)
plot(vec, type = "l")
```

[image]

But I want to plot this vector using `ggplot2` because its plots are better and more beautiful. But I'm struggling with it. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to R and I didn't know about these dataframe things!

Comment: It is in the first line of documentation of `?ggplot` description: "declare the input data frame". It might be a bit harsh for a beginner in R and for that I'm sorry, but I downvoted because you have enough reputation to suggest that you'd be able to either read documentation or use this site to find code examples for ggplot2. If you're looking to get started with ggplot2, the [book](https://ggplot2-book.org/getting-started.html) is a good place or otherwise you might like the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ggplot2/info).

Comment: @teunbrand Thanks, your right I should research more sorry for that. Well, but I'm still struggling with plotting a simple vector via ggplot!. I thought It was an easy 1 line code so I sked here to know that. But it seems it is not that easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the good answer of Leonardo, the short answer to my question (to graph a vector `vec` via ggplot) would be this:

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:length(vec), y = vec)
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```r
ggplot(as.data.frame(vec)) + 
  geom_point(aes(vec, sqrt(vec)))
```

It works, but I would like to advise you to create a dataframe before making the plot.

Let's say you want a plot with lines and/or points. One way to have control over what you do is:

1. Create a dataframe with an x ​​column and a y column

   ```r
   df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = 1:100)
   ```
2. pass the dataframe to `ggplot()`

   ```r
   ggplot(df)
   ```
3. add the `geom` you want by defining `x` and `y` in `aes`

   ```r
   ggplot(df) + 
     geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
     geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y))
   ```
4. customize your plot

**Note 1**: in step 3 you can define aes also in ggplot to not repeat the code:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

**Note 2**: in `aes`, `x` and `y` on the left of `=` are the names of the parameters, while `x` and `y` on the right of `=` are the names of the columns of the dataframe. The names of the `x` and `y` parameters can be omitted and you can leave only the name of the columns of the dataframe

Comment: Isn't defining `x = vec` a problem? because just in this case it works. What should I do in general?

Comment: I modified my answer to try to answer your question. If it helps, if you want, accept it

Comment: Thank you so much now I got it. could you please edit your answer to `data.frame(x = 1:length(vec), y = vec)` to be more general so I accept it?

Comment: I can do it, but it wouldn't be general. `x` and `y` are not necessarily ordered vectors of integers, so `x` does not necessarily go from `1` to `n` in steps of `1`. For example, you can also use data.frame (x = runif(100, 0, 1), y = sqrt (1 : 100)). The dataframe I used is just an example of infinitives and is more general than writing `1: length(vec)`

Comment: I say that because my problem was to plot a vector `vec` in ggplot like I plot it via `plot` function. don't you think `data.frame(x = 1:length(vec), y = vec)` it the general answer to it?

Comment: if you just want to plot a simple graph like `plot(sqrt(1: 100), type = "l")` you don't need to define a dataframe (and that's the first part of my answer). If you want to do things more generally you have to define a dataframe instead (and you asked "What should I do in general?" So I expanded the answer to deal with a general case